# "It is for people who" vs "it is for the/those people who"

Tags: articles, determiners, sentence-meaning

A. Mnemonics are for people who don't know.
B. Mnemonics are for the/those people who don't know.

Which one is correct? If both, what is the difference in sense/meaning?

Comment: I think there's a good question in here about the role of "those" in such sentences. But unless you really do want to sound like Henry David Thoreau, I'd stick with the former. ("Speech is for the convenience of those who are hard of hearing" HDT - *On Walden Pond*)

Comment: What is the change in the sense if I introduce the determiner, if any?

Comment: Or is the meaning of the sentence altered by adding "the/those", and in what way? The difference seems to be very subtle.

Comment: If there is a difference it is an extremely subtle one. I would suggest that by introducing "those" you make it sound as though there are few of them.

Comment: What about the implied meaning of "It is for those people who don't know --- not for me"? The first sentence sounds more neutral, and does not seem to carry the contrastive connotation.

Comment: May we drop the irrelevant “mnemonics” and consider only “people…” and “the/those people…”?
Without context, there is no useful difference.
With context, can you provide an example of each case, please?